# Why did `rails new myproject --webpack` not generate app/javascript or config/webpacker.yml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack

I'm using Rails 5.1.4 with Ruby 2.4.2 and following this tutorial about Rails modern front end set up; https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/evil-front-part-1.

This instructs me to start a new rails project with;

`rails new evil_chat --skip-coffee --skip-sprockets --skip-turbolinks --webpack --database=postgresql  -T`

Having done so, though i do find `gem 'webpacker'` in my gemfile, I do not have app/javascript/... or config/webpacker.yml in my new app's directory.

Any ideas what I've done wrong?

Comment: You can always just run the generator afterwards with `bundle exec rails webpacker:install`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visit the [installation](https://github.com/rails/webpacker#installation) guide. Your command is correct and you need to now install `Webpacker` with the command

```
bundle exec rails webpacker:install
```

Continue onto the `README` and review the [development](https://github.com/rails/webpacker#development) development guide. This will help you start your `webpacker`'s development server.

If you want to include a specific JS framework with your initial installation you can pass it in the `webpack` option like so:

```
--webpack=vue
```

Or if `webpack` was already installed use the command `bundle exec rails webpacker:install:vue` on the existing Rails app.

Comment: Thanks @jdgray, the tutorial didn't explicitly state that I needed to run the webpacker:install command. After following your instructions and the install guide everything's working as intended .